# Directory creation with session variable in PHP

Tags: php

My site allow to users upload sound file to server. A directory(like users name) create when user registered.

```
mkdir("speaking/uploads/".$myusername,0777);
```

When user want to login:

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

header("location:index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

I want to the uploaded file go to his folder but the files goes to uploads directory.

```
<?php

$uploads_dir = './uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'];

if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){
        echo 'ok';
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();
?>
```

How can do this please?
Is there any better and secure idea to do this?

Comment: NEVER EVER put data received from user into database unsanitized. At least do it like this: $myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);

Comment: Or use mysqli or PDO considering mysql is **deprecated**.

Comment: Thanks, I have this, but for summarize the code doesn't write here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the **session_start** and it will be blank so that`s why it is uploaded in the parent folder so change your code to:

```
<?php
session_start();//start the session first
$uploads_dir = './uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'];

if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){
        echo 'ok';
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I add session_start(); but still upload to _uploads_ directory.

Comment: Add in both scripts, after use PDO for database query

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are missing a `session_start()` here:

```
<?php
    // H E R E !
    session_start();

    $uploads_dir = './uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'];
```

Also, using folder names getting from user input (`$_POST['myusername']`) is a very bad idea, if unsanitized like it is here!!!

Comment: OK, what is the best idea for my mean and do this?